# How to find which percentile out of 100 a negative number is?

Tags: percentages

I'm having some logic/math problems in a program I'm trying to fix. So, suppose I have three values, 30, 25 and -15. The sum of these values is always going to be 100%. But I also need to know which percentile out of 100 the -15 is, if there is any, since the negative numbers need to be counted in the total sum. If I count the sum as 40, as in adding 25 and (-15), it's easy, but I wouldn't be able to know which percentile was the -15 because it is now a +10. I've used this formula: **P% * X = Y where P is what % of X is Y** but for it I would have to count 40 as being total, but I don't think I can just sum the numbers up. Does this make any sense? I'm sorry for not being able to be clear enough.

Comment: Are these for displaying to the user? I think you will have to tell us what these figures mean before we can give you a sensible answer.

Comment: This is so that the calculus always equals 100 so that the system can function properly. In this algorithm, the program receives a number of transactions and some of them can be negative. In this operation, it needs to know which percentile out of 100 each one of the transactions were. So if I get 50 and (-50), the program needs to calculate how many % was 50 and how many % was -50 out of 100%.

Comment: So, with your values $30, 25$ and $-15$, do you expect the answer $33.333\ldots\%$? (one third of all values is negative!)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only (somewhat) sensible calculation I can give you is the following: just follow the same rules that you follow when all the numbers are positive:

- Add them all together ($30+25-15=40$)
- Divide each of them by the total sum and multiply by $100\%$: $\frac{30}{40}\times 100\%=75\%, \frac{25}{40}\times 100\%=62.5\%, -\frac{15}{40}\times 100\%=-37.5\%$.

As you see, some percentages will end up being negative. In this case, you end up with the following percentages: $75\%, 62.5\%, -37.5\%$ which do add up to $100\%$.

It is the whole other question whether this calculation gives you what you need. (I cannot tell from your question alone.)

Also note, if your numbers add up to $0$, this calculation does not make sense.

Comment: Thank you. Sadly, I've confirmed the algorithm was way more complex than what the question had asked. Though you were great help, so I'll accept your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: @DootyBooty If my solution is wrong or misleading you shouldn't have accepted it - I cannot even delete it now that it is accepted!

Answer (score 0):

"Percentile" does not mean

- "percentage ratio of the sample value to mean"
- "percentage ratio of the sample value to the sum."

It means

- "percentage fraction of samples less than the given sample" or
- "percentage fraction of samples less than or equal to the given sample" or
- rounded or interpolated variations thereof, dependent on who you ask.

For your samples, the percentile of each sample depends on the definition, but

- for $-15$ is $0$ at least, $34$ at most;
- for $25$ is $33$ at least, $67$ at most; and
- for $30$ is $66$ at least, $100$ at most.